# Getting metadata from zip file using Java + Tika works very slow

Tags: java, zip, metadata, archive, apache-tika

I need to take as much metadata as I can from zip file, however I'm interested only in metadata connected with THIS file. As for now, I'm using Tika's PackageParser with context:

```
private ParseContext prepareContext() {
    final ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
    parseContext.set(Parser.class, new EmptyParser());
    return parseContext;
}
```

cause I want to skip parsing all children. But it still takes very long (~90sec for 8GB file). Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: How long does running `zip -l <filename.zip>` take on your machine? That'll give you an idea of the minimum time it'll take to scan through the zip for entries

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using windows, so can't execute this command, but when I use 7zip to check whole archive, it takes ~54 seconds. What's more, it checks every fileEntry in archive. As long, as I don't need info about children, I should be able to get all needed metadata just from analyzing central directory of zip (without parsing every file entry) - am I wrong? That's why I'm using EmptyParser for context in Tika. And parsing central directory (instead of every entry) should be much more quickly than this 90 sec.